# Delete / edit a tip via the Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm currently building a Food Safety website for local government, which lists the hygiene ratings of restaurants, cafés etc. I thought it would be cool to allow people to follow a page on Foursquare which gives people the hygiene ratings of a place when they check in via tips.

I have this all working in test, and was all ready to roll it out to live until I realised that when a place has been reinspected, there's no way (that I can see) to delete the old tip with the old rating and replace it with the new one.

A quick search tells me that there is indeed no way to delete tips via the API, which I totally understand the reasoning behind, but is there any way I can edit a tip programatically? If not, is there any other method I could look at for telling users the food hygiene scores of places they check into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible via the API, but it is not documented in the public API (perhaps intentionally). Foursquare's webpage uses the following API endpoint for deleting tips: `/v2/tips/#TIPID#/delete` (accepts only POSTs)

So you can use your system like that:

1. Get you Tip's id, e.g. via
   https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/tips or via https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/#VENUE_ID#/tips
2. Perform the following post to delete the tip:
   https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/#TIP_ID#/delete?oauth_token=#YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN#&v=20120321

I have used the endpoint several times. It is working as expected, but we have no guarantee that it remains in that way.